# Using OR operator in expect statement of Protractor

Tags: protractor, operators

How to use OR operator in expect statement. Below is my code

```
var now= someTime;
var nowPlus = someTime;
expect(updatedRefreshedTime).toEqual(now || nowMinus);
```

I want something like this.

Answer (score 1):

1) If `updatedRefreshedTime` is a promise.

```
var now= someTime;
var nowPlus = someTime;
updatedRefreshedTime.then(function(data){
   expect(data === now || data === nowMinus).toBe(true);
});
```

2) Otherwise

```
expect(updatedRefreshedTime === now || updatedRefreshedTime === nowMinus).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possibilities:

1. Without Chai:

You can create an array `[now, nowMinus]` and check is `updatedRefreshedTime` in an array.

2. With Chai:

Use [chai-quantifiers](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-quantifiers/) plugin. Second `it` in examples seems to be suitable for your issue.